# Find websocket session by id in Java EE 7

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, websocket, java-ee-7

I've read Java EE documentation and for me is unclear one thing. According to API, the only way to find another Session is a code like this: (assuming that we've identifier of other session):

```
import javax.websocket.Session;
...
private static Session findOtherSessionById(Session user, String id) {
    for (Session session : user.getOpenSessions()) {
        if (id.equals(session.getId())) {
            return session;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But when we've thousands of users, this code is a performance bottleneck.

So, is there a way to get Session by id fast without using own ConcurrentHashMap for this? Or maybe some application server has undocummented feature for this (for me Wildfly would be great)?

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm using hazelcast.Imap and it can't store websocket.Session object. I need all Session objects for broadcast all sessions.

Comment: Unfortunately not, currently I'm storing all Sessions in ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: our solution for clustered environments is using hazelcast topic to let know all clusters there is an event and they broadcast their stored sessions in map.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
Map<String, Session> map = new HashMap<>();
static Map<String, Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
   peers.put(session.getId(), session);
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session) {
    peers.remove(session.getId());
}

private static Session findOtherSessionById(Session user, String id) {
    if (peers.containsKey(user.getId()) {
        return peers.get(user.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have currently similar code with ConcurrentHashMap instead of synchronizedMap. I asked for another solution. Also when we have 2 application servers running, this code will fail.

Comment: @Ihromant for a distributed system you can use a distributed cache or information storage system, this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815056/distributed-hashmap-in-java-or-distributed-information-storage