# Distributed Hashmap in java or distributed information storage

Tags: java, dht

Does someone knows a good java framework for distributed hashmaps (DHT)?

Some time ago I worked with [Overlay Weaver](http://overlayweaver.sourceforge.net/), but a good documentation is missing here, so I only used it for an prototype with ugly hacks..., but now I need reliable code. Or does someone found a good docu for OverlayWeaver?

It would be perfect if the dht framework supports Chord or Kademlia and can be called inside my java application.

Or does someone knows a better approach to save reliable and failuresafe short string data in distibuted systems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.org) works fine for this type of situation. It practically requires no setup (more than that you need to add the dependencies to the Hazelcast jars). The following code sample shows how to setup a shared `Map`.

```
// Code in process 1
Config cfg = new Config();
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
Map<Integer, String> sharedData = instance.getMap("shared");
sharedData.put(1, "This is shared data");

// Code in process 2
Config cfg = new Config();
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
Map<Integer, String> sharedData = instance.getMap("shared");
String theSharedString = sharedData.get(1);
```

Hazelcast support various shared data structures including `Map`, `Queue`, `List`, `AtomicLong`, `IdGenerator` etc. [The documentation is good](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/manual/html-single/) and in my experience the implementation is solid.

If your are using a *sane* build environment (e.g. Maven) the following dependency is all that is needed to get started:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wow hazelcast is really amazing and easy. Thank you for this fast answer :-)

Comment: But it seems you can pay for it, so maybe it has some limitations. Do you know the limits of the free version?

Comment: Check this out for pricing: http://hazelcast.com/pricing/ - the Open Source alternative does not include support, Tomcat session clustering etc

Comment: But is there some rate limiting (e.g. many items in queue) in the free version? That is not mentioned here, so I guess there is none, but I dont know.

Comment: I would assume so since it is not mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com/).It is open-source and has Enterprise support.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [Redisson PRO](http://redisson.pro/). It supports [sharded maps](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson/wiki/5.-data-partitioning-(sharding)).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [Apache Ignite](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/getting-started) .
It supports In-memory distributed key-value store, Distributed Tasks, Durable Memory, Distributed Locks etc. It also support ANSI-99 complaint distributed SQLs.

Getting started is as simple as adding maven dependencies -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
```