# Current web socket session in ktor

Tags: kotlin, websocket, ktor

How can i get current web socket session?
I had an idea to do something like this:

```
webSocket("/echo") {
            println("WebSocket connection")

            val thisConnection = Connection(this)
            val session = call.sessions.get<ConnectionToUser>()

            if (session == null) {
                close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.NORMAL, "User not authorized"))
            } else {
                call.sessions.set(session.copy(connectionId = thisConnection.id, userId = session.userId))
            }
            //Some code
}
```

But i cant set sessions in webSocket.

Comment: To get the current connection, is there a reason why you use `Connection(this)`? The [docs](https://ktor.io/docs/websocket.html#WebSocketSession) for the interface of WebSocketSession may be useful here where you can call `this.call` inside `webSocket { ... }`

Comment: I need to be able to access the current web socket session in other places than `websocket {...}` Therefore, I use `Connection(this)` to send data over a web socket in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a concurrent map to store user sessions in memory. Here is the code example:

```
typealias UserId = Int

fun main() {
    val sessions = ConcurrentHashMap<UserId, WebSocketServerSession>()

    embeddedServer(CIO, port = 7777) {
        install(WebSockets)
        routing {
            webSocket("/auth") {
                val userId = 123
                sessions[userId] = this
            }

            webSocket("/") {
                val userId = 123
                val session = sessions[userId]

                if (session == null) {
                    close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.NORMAL, "User not authorized"))
                } else {
                    println("Session does exist")
                }
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

This solution was inspired by that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27045235/13963150).